# Can an interface have an enumerated key?

Tags: typescript

Say I have the following example:

```js
interface Price {
  currency: string;
  value: number;
}

interface Product {
  priceRetail: Price;
  priceWholesale: Price;
  priceDiscount: Price;
}
```

Is it possible to abbreviate to something like this?

```js
interface Product {
  [priceRetail, priceWholesale, priceDiscount]: Price;
}
```

Comment: <opinion>While it's possible, frankly it seems harder to read and maintain than just listing them.</opinion> 

Comment: For the example I gave I fully agree! Thanks

Comment: It's still an interesting and useful question though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a provided utility type in typescript named [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).

```
type Product = Record<"priceRetail" | "priceWholesale" | "priceDiscount", Price>;
```

**More on type Record:**
`Record<Keys, Type>`

> Constructs an object type whose property keys are Keys and whose property values are Type. This utility can be used to map the properties of a type to another type.

Comment: One of the great things about this is that if you need to include properties with different types as well (like the `example: boolean` one in my answer), it flows really well: `interface Product extends Record<"priceRetail" | "priceWholesale" | "priceDiscount", Price> { example: boolean; }`.

Comment: It is a pleasure for me to learn from such a great man as you. @T.J.Crowder, I've started following you to express my admiration.

Comment: You're too kind. And hey, **you're** the one who pointed to the best (IMHO) solution for the OP's question. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) *(but be sure to read [Amirhe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69809707/157247))*:

```typescript
type Product = {
    [Key in "priceRetail" | "priceWholesale" | "priceDiscount"]: Price;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApWE5BvAUMg5BAVyighAQE8AuZAZzAxAHMBufQgNzgBtiIdEMQC2AI2gcAvrlxgqABxToA9gBNiCMMgC8OTgQDaAaQhVkoZACIFGJACUIYOMF5XkAH2u3MEAOoAFiq8EPR8EO5eNnYQACLA9AgqxOBWALp06L7SbEA)

It's awkward to combine with other properties have have different types, though. For instance, if you wanted an `example` property of type `boolean` in addition to those `Price` properties, you'd have to use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types):

```typescript
type Product = {
    [Key in "priceRetail" | "priceWholesale" | "priceDiscount"]: Price;
} & {
    example: boolean;
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApWE5BvAUMg5BAVyighAQE8AuZAZzAxAHMBufQgNzgBtiIdEMQC2AI2gcAvrlxgqABxToA9gBNiCMMgC8OTgQDaAaQhVkoZACIFGJACUIYOMF5XkAH2u3MEAOoAFiq8EPR8EO5eNnYQACLA9AgqxOBWALp06L7SyABk+oTIEAAecCIKIXRiKsEQcCDSHEA)

...or in two steps with `extends` (which is [*basically* intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#interfaces-vs-intersections) though conflicts are handled differently):

```typescript
type ProductPrices = {
    [Key in "priceRetail" | "priceWholesale" | "priceDiscount"]: Price;
};
interface Product extends ProductPrices {
    example: boolean;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApWE5BvAUMg5BAVyighAQE8AuZAZzAxAHMBufQgNzgBtiIdEMQC2AI2gcAvrlxgqABxToA9gBNiCMOkwR6yALw5OBANoBpCFWShkAIgUYkAJQhg4wXneQAfe490AdQALFV49PghvPwcnCAARYHoEFWJwOwBdOh0kaQ5QSFhEZSh1TTBkCAAPSBA1fVUNLRy9Y0JKqrgRBXC6MRUwiDgQaVwgA)

Comment: One can use extends to avoid intersection type. `type _Prices = {
    [Key in "priceRetail" | "priceWholesale" | "priceDiscount"]: Price;
};

interface Product extends _Prices {
    flag: boolean;
}`. Interfaces tend to have nicer error messages compared to intersection types.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - Good point, I should mention that. (`extends` basically is intersection, after all, though I suspect there's nuance I'm not capturing there.)

Comment: How come does works with Type but not Interface?

Comment: @tvanbeek - Because mapping is a feature of type aliases, but not a feature of `interface` syntax -- but I don't know *why* that is. I suspect it's just that object type expressions (`{/*...*/}`) are just more flexible than `interface`.

Comment: There is also a type named `Record` that make things a little bit shorter

Comment: @Amirhe (Speaking off-topic: LOL -- I misread your username as "Amirite".)

Comment: @Amirhe - Doh! Of course, nice one! Do you want to post that as an answer? It seems like a good one to me.

Comment: Sorry for posting the off-topic, but I didn't mention that before @T.J.Crowder. You rocks man, thank you :)

Comment: @Amirhe - Sorry, bad phrasing on my part. **You** didn't post off-topic! I was just warning you that my comment about your username was off-topic. Sorry for the confusion. Your point about `Record` couldn't be more **on**-topic.

Comment: @tvanbeek - I wanted to wait for Amirhe to possibly post that as its own answer before adding it to the answer above. I think it's separate enough, and I'm hoping they post it. If they don't, I'll mark this answer community wiki and add it, but I'd rather encourage younger members to post good answers like that.

Comment: You are so nice, Okay I will post the Record separately. Thank you again.